# In MongoDB's pymongo, how do I do a count()?

Tags: mongodb, count, pymongo, database

```
for post in db.datasets.find({"test_set":"abc"}).sort("abc",pymongo.DESCENDING).skip((page-1)*num).limit(num):
```

How do I get the `count()`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you're using pymongo version 3.7.0 or higher, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54759357/405015) instead.

---

If you want `results_count` to ignore your `limit()`:

```
results = db.datasets.find({"test_set":"abc"}).sort("abc",pymongo.DESCENDING).skip((page-1)*num).limit(num)
results_count = results.count()

for post in results:
```

If you want the `results_count` to be capped at your `limit()`, [set `applySkipLimit` to `True`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor.count):

```
results = db.datasets.find({"test_set":"abc"}).sort("abc",pymongo.DESCENDING).skip((page-1)*num).limit(num)
results_count = results.count(True)

for post in results:
```

Comment: @Jake: What do you suggest instead?

Comment: results_count = results.count(True) http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/  I think I misread your post though.  I stopped at the first for loop. I see now that you have that mentioned.  Sorry for flying by the seat of my pants.

Answer (score 63):

Since pymongo version 3.7.0 and above [count() is deprecated](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/changelog.html#changes-in-version-3-7-0). Instead use [`Collection.count_documents`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents). Running `cursor.count` or `collection.count` will result in following warning message:

```
DeprecationWarning: count is deprecated. Use Collection.count_documents instead.
```

To use `count_documents` the code can be adjusted as follows

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()
col = db[DATABASE][COLLECTION]

find = {"test_set":"abc"}
sort = [("abc",pymongo.DESCENDING)]
skip = 10
limit = 10

doc_count = col.count_documents(find, skip=skip)
results = col.find(find).sort(sort).skip(skip).limit(limit)

for doc in result:
   //Process Document
```

**Note:** `count_documents` method performs relatively slow as compared to `count` method. In order to optimize you can use [`collection.estimated_document_count`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.estimated_document_count). This method will return estimated number of docs(as the name suggested) based on collection metadata.

Comment: This is an annoying change. Now, instead of making find request, and then `.count`ing the result Cursor, you need to make *two* calls, one to run count_documents, and one to get the actual results. This seems wasteful with complex filters (I don't know if it actually is). For small results sets `len(list(cursor))` could work, but that's going to be a terrible idea on a large result set...

Comment: for copy pasters, using the var name `filter` will redefine python `filter` function, could result in unexpected behaviour of your code

Answer (score 10):

Not sure why you want the count if you are already passing limit 'num'. Anyway if you want to assert, here is what you should do.

```
results = db.datasets.find({"test_set":"abc"}).sort("abc",pymongo.DESCENDING).skip((page-1)*num).limit(num)

results_count = results.count(True)
```

That will match **results_count** with **num**

Answer (score 6):

if you wants all the records count(without any filter) in a collection then use this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
cl = pymongo.MongoClient(host="localhost", port=27017)
db = cl["database_name"]
print(db.get_collection("collection_name").estimated_document_count())
```

Answer (score 5):

Cannot comment unfortuantely on @Sohaib Farooqi's answer... Quick note: although, `cursor.count()` has been deprecated it is significantly faster, than `collection.count_documents()` in all of my tests, **when counting all documents in a collection (ie. filter={})**. Running `db.currentOp()` reveals that `collection.count_documents()` uses an aggregation pipeline, while `cursor.count()` doesn't. This might be a cause.

Answer (score 1):

This thread happens to be 11 years old. However, in 2022 the 'count()' function has been deprecated. Here is a way I came up with to count documents in MongoDB using Python. Here is a picture of the code snippet. Making a empty list is not needed I just wanted to be outlandish. Hope this helps :). [Code snippet here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlGTu.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use cursor and also want count, you can try this way

```py
# Have 27 items in collection
db = MongoClient(_URI)[DB_NAME][COLLECTION_NAME]

cursor = db.find()
count = db.find().explain().get("executionStats", {}).get("nReturned")
# Output: 27

cursor = db.find().limit(5)
count = db.find().explain().get("executionStats", {}).get("nReturned")
# Output: 5

# Can also use cursor
for item in cursor:
      ...
```

You can read more about it from https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.explain

Answer (score 0):

The thing in my case relies in the count of matched elements for a given query, and surely not to repeat this query twice:

**one** to get the count, and
**two** to get the result set.

*no way*

I know the query result set is not quite big and fits in memory, therefore, I can convert it to a list, and get the list length.

This code illustrates the use case:

```py
# pymongo 3.9.0
while not is_over:
  it = items.find({"some": "/value/"}).skip(offset).size(limit)
  # List will load the cursor content into memory
  it = list(it)
  if len(it) < size:
    is_over = True
  offset += size
```