# Cursor.count() gives AttributeError in pymongo 4.3.3

Tags: python, cursor, pymongo

As the title suggests, I am trying to use `count()` with a `find()` on a collection but it keeps throwing the error `AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'count'`.

For reference, I went through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415514/in-mongodbs-pymongo-how-do-i-do-a-count) but `count_documents()` seems to be tehre for colelctions themselves, and not cursors. The other option mentioned was `len(list(cursor))` but I can't use that as it consumes the cursor itself (can't iterate over it after this). I went through a couple more answers, but these seem to be the main ways out.

Moreover, my pymongo version is `4.3.3` which can't be changed due to some restrictions.

Is there any operation I can perform directly on `Cursor` which doesn't consume it?

##### Sample code

```py
def temp(col):
    return col.find().count()

print(temp(collection))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list()` will exhaust the cursor, but save its ouput to a variable and you can access it multiple times, e.g.

```
records = list(col.find())
num_records = len(records)

for record in records:
    # do stuff
```